# How to efficiently detect Region1 is within Region2?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to efficiently detect Region1 is within Region2?

My approach so far is using [hit testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-use-hit-testing-with-a-region) to check if each point in Region1 is within Region2 which is very slow.

Please note that Region1 and Region2 are irregular shapes.

Code example:

Region1 (17,6) (25,6) (25,24) (17,24) (17,6)

Region2 (34,6) (834,11) (832,327) (759,331) (17,321) (21,220) (17,47) (29,16) (34,6)

From this example, Region1 is not totally inside Region2. Codes from Reza and nvoigt do not work for me.

Comment: The Region class has an usual Equals() method, the one that takes an extra Graphics argument.  Which is what you want to use to check if Region.Intersect() produces the same region.

Answer (score 1):

You could use union: bascially, when you join r1 and r2 and it's still r1, r2 was completely inside r1:

```
Region r1 = ...
Region r2 = ...

Graphics g = ...

Region u = r1.Clone();
u.Union(r2);

var r1_contained_r2 = u.Equals(r1, g);
```

This might not be very optimized though. Less code:

```
Region r1 = ...
Region r2 = ...

Graphics g = ...

var r1_contained_r2 = r1.Clone().Complement(r2).IsEmpty(g);
```

Comment: You have my vote for the answer because of being faster in answering the question. I made it as an extension method to make it more useful for future readers.

Comment: I think my question is not clear. I meant Region1 is TOTALLY within Region2. I run your code and this is result. Your code returns True while it is not.
Region1
(17,6)
(25,6)
(25,24)
(17,24)
(17,6)
Region2
(34,6)
(834,11)
(832,327)
(759,331)
(17,321)
(21,220)
(17,47)
(29,16)
(34,6)

Answer (score 1):

To create a `Contains` method for `Region` class, you can rely on [`Region.Equals(Region, Graphics)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yx605z9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method. To do so, you can create an extension method like this:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
public static class RegionExtension
{
    public static bool Contains(this Region thisRegion, Region r)
    {
        using (var thisClone = thisRegion.Clone())
        {
            using (var g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                thisClone.Intersect(r);
                return thisClone.Equals(r, g);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use it, it's enough to test it this way:

```
var b = region1.Contains(region2);
```

Comment: For the data that you shared with us, here is [the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fSGb.png) of those regions which shows the method is working correctly.